# Using ToString to display a Date to the first of the month. Should I?

Tags: c#, date, tostring

I need to add a date to a contract.  The lawyers say the date must be displayed as the first of the month.

In the past I've always created a new date, and formatted that date for the display.

```
 NewEffDate = new DateTime(effectiveDate.Year, effectiveDate.Month, 1);
 NewEffDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

It occurred to me, I could simply do this when I format the date for display.

```
   effectiveDate.ToString("MM/1/yyyy");
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't do it with ToString?

I'm wondering if I'm dense for not seeing this previously or dense because it's not a good idea to do this when formatting.

Comment: Why are you converting to a string anyways?  Seems like you should create a new date so you can do sorting/comparing/etc. properly.

Comment: They both have the same outcome, so I would go with the `.ToString("MM/1/ yyyy")`  since it's more readable.

Comment: I don't know your code, obviously, but on the face of what you've said I don't see this being a problem. That varies depending on your usage of this value though, and only you can really answer that

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  For this problem the code only inserts the new date into an xml file that will get passed along to generate the contract document. It is only used on that contract exactly as it appears in the xml.  It is never used for anything else or stored anywhere.  I was trying to figure out if it was good form to use the formating to change the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - no, looks fine.
The longer answer - it depends: what else do you do with `NewEffDate`? how many lines of code separate from it to its `ToString`? These questions will guide to an easier maintenance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to print this date, you are free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the following to get the first day of the month:

```
NewEffDate = new DateTime(effectiveDate.Year, effectiveDate.Month, 1);
```

followed by using this piece of your code:

```
NewEffDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Anyway, your solution works too and it is save to use it. But I prefer using the above code for this problem.